# Matching words in a sentence using Perl?

Tags: perl

i want to extract words between two words in perl but i dont know i can use regular expression or any lib to do that?

example:

```
$sen = "A short quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog running in the market";

@sentence = split / /, $sen;
foreach my $word (@sentence) {

}
```

i want to get the words between **brown** and **lazy** together with 2 words from the left and 2 words from the right.

```
output:

words between: fox jumps over the
2 words from left: short quick
2 words from right: dog running
```

how can i come up with the above output?

Answer (score 3):

Is this homework? If so then you should say so in your question and the answers you get will be aimed towards helping you to learn rather than simply offering a solution.

You are declaring an array with one element containing the entire sentence string, including the opening and closing double quotes. That cannot be what you intended as your loop will execute just once with $word set to the sentence string.

You must start every Perl program with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to make debugging easier.

The code below does what you describe.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sentence = "A short quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog running in the market";
my @sentence = split ' ', $sentence;

my @sample = grep /fox/ .. /the/, @sentence;
print "words between: @sample\n";

@sample = @sentence[-2..-1];
print "2 words from right: @sample\n";

@sample = @sentence[0..1];
print "2 words from right: @sample\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
words between: fox jumps over the
2 words from right: the market
2 words from right: A short
```

Comment: its not an assignment its a project im working on, i want to match 'brown quick' as left, 'lazy dog' as right not first two or last two from your solution, thanks a lot